# Syntastic not working on Ubuntu

Tags: vim, syntastic

I hate to post an "I can't work syntastic" question, but this has me stumped.

Standard dotfiles setup - same config on OSX, Debian & now Ubuntu. Syntastic is not showing any errors in a broken Python file on Ubuntu. The same setup works on OSX/Debian.

Using `test.py`, which contains only a single line:

```
import json
```

`:SyntasticInfo` output is the same on OSX/Ubuntu/Debian:

```
Syntastic version: 3.7.0-157 (Vim 704, Linux)
Info for filetype: python
Global mode: active
Passive filetypes: java sass scss
Filetype python is active
The current file will be checked automatically
Available checkers: pyflakes python
Currently enabled checkers: pyflakes python
```

`:SyntasticCheck` does nothing, likewise `:Errors`.

I forcefully show errors by running `:echo system('pyflakes test.py')` in vim, which produces:

```
test.py:1: 'json' imported but unused
```

My syntastic `.vimrc` config is (from my [dotfiles](https://github.com/mafrosis/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/.vimrc#L157)):

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['pyflakes', 'python']
let g:syntastic_python_pyflakes_exe = 'python3 -m pyflakes'
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args='--ignore=E501'
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active',
                           \ 'active_filetypes': [],
                           \ 'passive_filetypes': ['java', 'sass', 'scss'] }
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future visitors, the mistake I made relates to the following config option:

```
let g:syntastic_python_pyflakes_exe = 'python3 -m pyflakes'
```

In order to debug the above checker, the command I should run in vim is:

```
:echo system('python3 -m pyflakes test.py')
```

Which told me that `pyflakes` was not available for `python3`...

Comment: Future visitor here. Thanks for sharing!